# Unable to submit form in 404 page

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess

I created a custom 404 page. In custom 404 page i placed a report broken link form . it is very simple form . But when i try to submit the form it is not working , i am not getting any values in post

```
headers :    
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 404
    [REQUEST_URI] => /mobiles/hd-s-phones-price-list.html 
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /custom404.php 
    [PHP_SELF] => /custom404.php
```

here is the code

### .httaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /custom404.php
```

### HTML

```
<div class="bbox">
        <b>Tell Us To Fix This Broken Link </b>
        <div class="bbox2">             
        <form name="custom_404" action="<?php HTTP.'custom404.php'; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
            <br class="clear" />
            <label>What you are looking for</label>
            <br class="clear" />
            <input type="text" name="looking" value="" />           
            <label>Name</label>
            <br class="clear" />
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['visitorname']!='' ? $_SESSION['visitorname'] : ''; ?>" />       
            <label>Email</label>
            <br class="clear" />
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['visitoremail']!='' ? $_SESSION['visitoremail'] : ''; ?>">
            <label>We will Mail You the exact links you are looking for</label>
            <br class="clear" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit_error" value="Report us" />

        </form>

        </div>
    </div>

<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Result i am getting when i print post is just empty `array()`

Comment: Try setting your action in the form to `custom404.php`

Comment: @MagnusBurton I checked by setting the action , but it is not working

Comment: What does the variable HTTP contain?

Comment: He can just as well leave it empty as he is sending it to the same page

Comment: HTTP  is defined constant for my url

Comment: Did any one found solution

Comment: Why do you need to submit a form when you already have all the info from `$_SESSION` and `$_SERVER` arrays anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an *echo* in

```
<form name="custom_404" action="<?php HTTP.'custom404.php'; ?>" method="post">
```

which results in action="".

Your code should look like this:

```
<form name="custom_404" action="<?php echo HTTP.'custom404.php'; ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to submit the form on the same page then let the action will be blank. It will be posted on the same url.

`<form name="custom_404" action="" method="post">`

This will also work.